# How do i get the value from textbox and pass it as an argument in a php function

Tags: php

I am quiet a bit new to php programming and html and was wondering is it possible to pass a value inputted into a textbox by the user into a php function ? For example, If the user enters *56* in the textbox, I want to retrieve that value and pass it as an arguement in a function(lets say, the argument for the function is:

```
          function add($userinput ) {
           $total = $userinput + 5;
           }
```

)

Can someone guide me in the right direction, i am a beginner php programmer. Any help would be appreciated. 
Below is my php/html code.

```
   public function getOptionsColumnHTML() {
    $html =<<< END
   <input type="checkbox" name="dtLatLng_Lat%ROW%" id="dtLatLng_Lat%ROW%" checked="checked" />
<label for="dtLatLng_Lat%ROW%">{$this->L["latitude"]}</label>&nbsp;
base:&nbsp;
<input type="text"name="dtval%ROW%" id="dtval%ROW%" style="width:50px; /> 
    <label for="dtval%ROW%">{$this->L["val"]}  </label>

    dist:&nbsp;
<input type="text"name="dtval%ROW%" id="dtval%ROW%" style="width:20px; /> 
    <label for="dtval%ROW%">{$this->L["val"]}  </label>
    <br>

  <input type="checkbox" name="dtLatLng_Lng%ROW%" id="dtLatLng_Lng%ROW%"   checked="checked" />
<label for="dtLatLng_Lng%ROW%">{$this->L["longitude"]}</label>
base:&nbsp;
<input type="text"name="dtvalue%ROW%" id="dtvalue%ROW%" style="width:60px;/> 
    <label for="dtvalue%ROW%">{$this->L["value"]}  </label>

dist:&nbsp;
<input type="text"name="dtval%ROW%" id="dtval%ROW%" style="width:20px; /> 
    <label for="dtval%ROW%">{$this->L["val"]}  </label>

 <br>
 Options:         
<input type="radio" name="dtSTD%ROW%" id="dtSTD%ROW%"  />     
<label for="dtSTD%ROW%">{$this->L["STD"]} STD </label>&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="dtMAX%ROW%" id="dtMAX%ROW%" />
<label for="dtMAX%ROW%">{$this->L["MAX"]} MAX </label>
   END;
    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write the code like below.

```
<?php
function add($userinput ) {
    $total = $userinput + 5;
    echo $total; // the total will be displayed here.
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    add($_POST['temp_textbox']);
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="temp_textbox" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Hope this will be helpful to you. Thanks!